# cannot install django 2.0.6 using pipenv

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

following the author's step, saw this command
 `$ pipenv install django==2.0.6` 
 in a book **Django for beginners** it seems to have been working for the author but when I try to execute it on the terminal it gives me following error.

```
    sysadmin@R902R6HD:~/Desktop/helloworld$ pipenv install django=2.0.6
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
Installing django=2.0.6...
⠋WARNING: Invalid requirement, parse error at "u'=2.0.6'"
ABORTING INSTALL... You will have to reinstall any packages that failed to install.
You may have to manually run pipenv lock when you are finished.
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/_compat.py:113: ResourceWarning: Implicitly cleaning up <TemporaryDirectory '/tmp/pipenv-67QFfh-requirements'>
  warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)
sysadmin@R902R6HD:~/Desktop/helloworld$ pipenv install django==2.0.6
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
Installing django==2.0.6...
Collecting django==2.0.6

Error:  An error occurred while installing django==2.0.6!
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.0.6 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14)
No matching distribution found for django==2.0.6
```

Comment: "The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python 2.7."  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/

Comment: python3 is installed in my system but this command is using python 2, I don't know why?

Comment: maybe you have to setup a new virtual env, with `pipenv --python 3.6` (or whatever version you have) to specify explicitly the version you want to use [(doc)](https://docs.pipenv.org/basics/#specifying-versions-of-python)

Comment: trying this post https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/729

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add two equal signs (==). You typed `pipenv install django=2.0.6` which should be `pipenv install django==2.0.6`.

Comment: later I corrected that but no luck solving this issue.